# Экран смерти 0x00000027

Tags: windows, bsod

Столкнулся с синим экраном на своем Windows Server 2012 R2, который выступает   роли RDSH хоста. BSOD имеет код RDP-FILE-SYSTEM и ошибку 0x00000027. На моем сервере создался файл-дамп 67 ГБ. Я проанализировал его, и там был код ZEROED_STACK_0x27. Я старался самостоятельно найти причину, читали материалы из вот этого [источника](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1883007-bug-check-0x00000027-and-blue-screen-of-death-message-rdbss-sys), вот [этого](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/7507d61a-1631-416f-ab09-03750161a4dc/bsod-issue-pointing-to-rdbsssys-on-windows-server-2012?forum=winserver8gen) и вот [этого](http://pyatilistnik.org/error-0x00000027-blue-screen-rdbss-sys/). Как я понял, есть некий драйвер rdbss.sys, который конфликтует с каким-то другим приложением, обращающимся к нему. Можете подсказать, что можно сделать, как точно найти его?

Comment: Какие вы используете утилиты на вашем RDSH хосте и локальном?

Comment: Набор стандартный, на терминале офис, 1с, хром, пдф ридер